# Python - List index out of range in 2d list

Tags: python

I'm a Python noob but I don't get why this isn't working. All I'm trying to do is output a 2d list with two values [[1,2] , [3, 4]] I've spent the majority of the morning trying to figure this out so I'm just gonna seek help.

```
class Tiling:
    def __init__(self, width, height, tileSize):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        self._tileSize = tileSize
        self._numTiles = (width / tileSize) * (height / tileSize)
        self._positions = []


    def tileMap(self):
        i = 0
        yCounter = 0
        x = []
        y = []
        for j in range(0, self._width, 32):
            x.append(j)
        for k in range(0, self._height, 32):
            y.append(k)
        while len(self._positions) < (self._numTiles):
            self._positions.append([x[i], y[yCounter]])
            if self._positions[i][0] == self._width:
                i = 0
                yCounter = yCounter + 1
            if i < len(x):
                i = i + 1

        return self._positions


tileObject = Tiling(800, 608, 32)
test = tileObject.tileMap()
print(test)
```

The traceback is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\gaming only\Desktop\PyMap\tiling.py", line 30, in <module>
        test = tileObject.tileMap()
      File "C:\Users\gaming only\Desktop\PyMap\tiling.py", line 19, in tileMap
        self._positions.append([x[i], y[yCounter]])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Always post the traceback of the error when asking for help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. What is the expected output for `Tiling(800, 608, 32).tileMap()`?

Comment: You should use the python debugger !

Answer (score 0):

If the code as posted is accurate, only 1 item ever got put into y (the line to append to y isn't in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

If we have an list with `n` items, the `len` function for that return `n`.

But beacuse index of an list, start from `zero`, if we want to loop through it, we must loop until `n-1`.

So change this line:

```
    if i < len(x):
        i = i + 1
```

To:

```
    if i < len(x) - 1:
        i = i + 1
```

Now your code can run:

```
[[0, 0], [32, 0], [64, 0], [96, 0], [128, 0], ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
def tileMap(self):
    self._positions = [ (x, y)
                           for y in range(0, self._height, self._tileSize)
                               for x in range(0, self._width, self._tileSize) ]
    return self._positions
```